# `/etc/zshenv` runs twice for interactive, non-login shell in iTerm2

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to get a handle on my shell startup files, and I can't figure out why my `etc/zshenv` runs twice. I've got echo statements in all of my startup files, and this is what I'm getting:

```
In /etc/zshenv
In ~/.zshenv for user: davidkennell
In /etc/zshrc
In ~/.zshrc for user: davidkennell
In /etc/zshenv
```

I have zsh set as my shell via my iTerm2 preferences, telling it in the `Profiles/general` settings to start the shell by running `/usr/local/bin/zsh`

Comment: By any chance do you source `/etc/zshenv` from your `~/.zshrc`? If not, you could temporarily add `set -x` to `/etc/zshenv` and then at the end of your `~/.zshrc` put `set +x`, this would print every single command that is executed between the `set -x` and the `set +x`, and this might help you pin down why it's getting sourced a second time. You can find some nice flowcharts describing the sequence if you want some more details [here](https://blog.flowblok.id.au/2013-02/shell-startup-scripts.html)

Comment: @DavidKennel : Does perhaps one of the files in your startup scripts (such as `~/.zshrc` or `~/.zshenv` invoke some zsh-script?  Since the second execution of `/etc/zshenv` seems to happen while `.zshrc` is being processed, I would use `set -x` to find out exactly, at which point this happens.

Answer (score 2):

Given the order of the messages, something in your `.zshrc` causes `/etc/zshenv` to be executed. This can be either a call to source `/etc/zshenv` or an invocation of another instance of zsh. Look for things like

```
. /etc/zshenv
source /etc/zshenv
zsh -c …
zsh /path/to/file
/path/to/file                             # which starts with #!/usr/bin/env zsh
```

or variations of these.

Note that the offending line might be either in `.zshrc` itself or in another file that it sources.

You can run `zsh -x` or `zsh -f -x ~/.zshrc` and look for the offending command in the trace. It may be easier than finding it in the source code.

The case of executing another program that happens to be a zsh script is the hardest to detect. For this, it may be easier to [monitor access to `/etc/zshenv`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14409/how-to-monitor-file-access-for-an-os-x-application). On the other hand, if that's what's going on, it's perfectly normal and there is nothing to do about it.

Comment: So I think the offending line in my `~/.zshrc` is `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`  - commenting it out seems to stop the accessing of `/etc/zshenv`. However, running `zsh -f -x /Users/davidkennell/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh` fills up my entire terminal w/ output, and looking through the source of the file show me that it sources many more oh-my-zsh files. Would love to be able to monitor access out of curiosity, but most tools at the link provided specifically monitor for changes to a file, not when the file is read or sourced. Or, they only work when an app you built it accessing the file. :/